# Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to perform a very big sum.

I have used `ulong` data type to store the sum value. But I keep getting the Runtime error.

```
static void Main(String[] args) {
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    string[] arr_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    int[] arr = Array.ConvertAll(arr_temp,Int32.Parse);

    ulong sum = (ulong)arr.Sum();
    Console.WriteLine(sum);

}
```

**Input**

1000000001 1000000002 1000000003 1000000004 1000000005

**Expected Output**

5000000015

Comment: int32 is too small?  try to use int64.Parse instead maybe.  [int32 size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The expression `(ulong)arr.Sum()` is invoking `Enumerable.Sum<int>()`, which performs the summation using the `int` data type, then casts the result to `ulong`.  This means that the result must be in the domain of the `int` data type to avoid overflow, but it is not.

You can resolve this a number of ways.  Perhaps the easiest would be to cast the numbers to `ulong` before summing, but then you have to deal with the fact that there is no `Enumerable.Sum()` overload that accepts `ulong`.

Not to worry; we can just use `Enumerable.Aggregate()` to define the operation ourselves:

```
ulong sum = arr
    .Select(i => (ulong)i)       // Convert elements to ulong
    .Aggregate((a, b) => a + b); // Sum
```

You could also parse the numbers as `ulong`s instead of `int`s:

```
ulong[] arr = Array.ConvertAll(arr_temp, ulong.Parse);

ulong sum = arr.Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
```

Note that there is an `Enumerable.Sum()` overload for the `long` data type, so you could consider using that instead.

Comment: I don't think your first solution works, as `Sum()`does not have an overload taking `IEnumerable<ulong>`

Comment: D'oh. I'm so used to C++ templates that I forget C# has holes like that since it can't generically apply operators. Fixed.

Comment: You'll also need `.Select(item => ulong.Parse(item))` instead of `Cast<ulong>`

Comment: I think you mean `.Select(i => (ulong)i)`. I forgot that `Cast<T>` is part of `Enumerable` and not `Enumerable<T>`, so the elements are boxed. But `ulong.Parse()` has no `int` overload and there is no implicit conversion from `int` to `string`, so your code wouldn't work either.